# How can i use jQuery's .find method with a regular expression as the parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, regex, search

I have an xml that i'd like to search for "alike" results, similar to what `LIKE` does in SQL.
I thought about doing something like `$(xml).find('regexHere')`, but i don't know how to do that.
If that's not the best method, could you recommend something else? The data i need to search is within node's parameters.

EDIT

`$(xml).find('[cityName=Rio de Janeiro]')`gives me exactly the node i'm searching for, because it's exactly the same string. But, if i search for `Rio`i don't get any results, even though the nodes of *Rio* de Janeiro and *Rio* Claro have the string i'm looking for.

I tried using `$(xml).find('[cityName|="Rio"]')` without luck, not a single result comes up, but if i change to `Rio de Janeiro`i get exactly what i need.

Comment: Do you need just some text from inside that node, or a branch of the DOM tree?

Comment: Ideally, the xml nodes. I'll add some code to the question, to clarify a bit.

Comment: I think you're looking for `[cityName*=rio]` if you're handling it this way.

Comment: @Bill Criswell No, it didn't work like a charm. :(
I got an error when searching for a string with spaces in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all elements that have an attribute matching a certain regex, you can use `.find("*")` to select all elements and then `.filter(...)` to remove any that don't match:

For example, to find all nodes whose `message` attribute contains "hello world":

```
var elements = $(xml).find("*").filter(function() {
    return /[Hh]ello [Ww]orld/.test($(this).attr("message"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That was straight to the point of my question, but i ended using @Bill Criswell's solution that he gave in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate selectors with a comma or you can use `.contents()` and `.filter()`.