# JQuery XML Find Attribute Case Insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a search field, if I type **board** it returns nothing but if I type **Board** it does.
I started searching and found out that unlike HTML, XHTML is case sensitive....

Example XML

```
<prop-db>
 <prop caption="Sign Board A" />
</prop-db>
```

JS Snippet

```
switch (last_search) {
    case "show_all":
        load('prop-db > prop');
        break;
    default:
        load('prop-db > prop[caption*="{0}"]'.format(last_search));
}
```

The default case attempts to find whatever the user entered in the search_field.
This is how the load function gets the elements with captions:

```
if (!search) {
    data2 = $(data).find('prop-db > prop').slice(-18);
} else { //gets executed when search equals true (when load is called with a parameter)
    data2 = $(data).find(syntax);
}
```

**So it should find each element that contains either Board/board/BoaRD etc...(find should be case insensitive)**

EDIT - tried this with filter + regex, I know im doing something wrong....:

```
data2 = $(data).find(syntax).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(new RegExp(str, 'i'));
});
```

Comment: Suggestion: explicitly ask your question.

Comment: I edited that just now at the bottom of OP...

Comment: this looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009315/need-help-to-make-jquery-find-case-insensitive

Comment: @HenryFlorence right but how do I incorporate a filter (as stated in that post) with the find method for XML?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262402/how-can-i-use-jquerys-find-method-with-a-regular-expression-as-the-parameter I guess, you could `.filter()` the `.find(syntax)` with the case insensitive regex

Comment: @HenryFlorence Ok I added what I could find out at the bottom of OP but it's still not working, I know I am doing something wrong...but what is it?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var regex = new RegExp(str, 'i');
data2 = $(data).find('prop-db > prop').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('caption').match(regex);
};
```

`.text()` will return the contents of the `<prop />` xml element, which in the example in the post is the empty string. Instead we need to test the caption attribute of the `<prop />` element.

Moving the creation of the regex object creation out of the loop, will ensure that only one object should be created no matter how many elements are checked.